# How to precisely sync the VM clock to the host clock

Tags: virtual-machine

Is there any way to precisely sync the guest clock to the host clock?

In my application the host is running PTP (slave mode) and **I need the VM clock to be synchronized precisely to the host clock**. I didn't find any way to sync the guest in a **level of PTP/1588 accuracy** which is **less than 1 µs**.

Comment: I would assume the VM would query the time from the bios, which it gets from the host, so no sync is necessary?

Comment: If you are on Windows you probably can't - read chapter 20 https://www.meinbergglobal.com/download/burnicki/Computer%20Time%20Synchronization%20Concepts%20-%202014-04-29.pdf

Comment: The simplest method.  Set the NTP server to both the host and guest to the same source.  Honestly though you would be hard pressed to sync your host within 1 µs to begin with.  There is going to be drift.  It happens.